# How to add days in datetime field in email template(mako template)?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, mako, openerp-8

I want add number of days in datetime field in email template, as like in python code:

```
datetime.strptime(date_order_str, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + relativedelta(days=10)
```

same code in template,  `${(object.date_order + days)}`

How can i do this?

Thanks for your valuable reply

Comment: call a function from the mako template and return value as you want :)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating Python code block and assigning result to variable which will be used as value in input file.

Example:

```
<%
    your_date_val = datetime.strptime(date_order_str, DEFAULT_SERVER_DATETIME_FORMAT) + relativedelta(days=10)
%>

<input type="datetime" value="${your_date_val}"/>
```

I hope it will solve your problem.